# Is placing the filter condition inside the join on statement equivalent?

Tags: sql, oracle

I always assumed that a statement of the following form

```
SELECT * FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON (A.column1 = B.column2 AND B.column2 = 12321)
```

is always equivalent to

```
SELECT * FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON (A.column1 = B.column2)
WHERE B.column2 = 12321
```

---

In more general terms:

```
SELECT * FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON (FOREIGN-KEY AND FILTER_ON(B))
WHERE FILTER_ON(A)
```

should be equivalent to

```
SELECT * FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON (FOREIGN-KEY)
WHERE FILTER_ON(A) AND FILTER_ON(B)
```

This does not seem to be the case... The first type gives a larger number of resulting rows than the second.

**Question**: In which cases is my assumption wrong?

Comment: The best way to learn SQL is by programming. Create the tables, insert some data and see if there's a difference or not! (Hint: There is. Put right side table conditions in the ON clause, otherwise you'll get regular inner join result.)

Comment: The best way to understand is: In the query are only records displayed if they match the where condition - on the other hand, if there is no match in the left join condition, the record is displayed, but with an empty row for the left joined table... (If you use a normal join (no left join) then the two statements are equivalent, but not for left, right or full joins.)

Comment: @jarlh I don't think this question warrants the go-and-learn-sql-first comment. Mathtec, welcome aboard!

Answer (score 8):

No.  For an outer join, they are not equivalent.

A `left join` keeps *all* rows in the first table, regardless of whether the `on` clause evaluates to true, false, or `NULL`.  So, a condition in the `on` on only the *first* table has no effect.

If you want filtering on the *first* table in a `left join`, put the conditions in the `where`.  Conditions on the second table generally go in the `on` clause.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! I have updated the question and I still do not understand why the filtering-condition on the second table B has different effects on the results in the join-condition.

Answer (score 2):

In your first Query you written `LEFT JOIN` that means left side tables all data.

Query:1 
`SELECT * FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON (FOREIGN-KEY AND FILTER_ON(A) AND FILTER_ON(B))`

Query:2 
`SELECT * FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON (FOREIGN-KEY)
WHERE FILTER_ON(A) AND FILTER_ON(B)`


In Query:1, Having condition in `LEFT JOIN` that means still we have LEFT side tables all data and  `NULL` values with `Table B` when condition getting false.

If you write condition in `where` clause(Query:2) for `table B` then there will be data mismatch in result of Query 1 & Query 2. because data will be filtered out in query result by condition.